# Move cursor outside of table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VB to write a macro in Word. what i need to do is, if i am within a table
i need to move out of it.
so if

```
x = Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)
```

then i have to move out.

What is the code to move out of the table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, that depends of course exactly where you want to move to - before or after the table or somewhere quite different; your question is a bit vague.

This code will get you out of the table and put the text cursor directly behind it:

```
Selection.Tables(1).Select
Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```